# SOQL Issue, Please correct me, I am getting 'Unknown error parsing query'

Tags: soql

```
SELECT AccountId, Id, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Sic = '6752']
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is called *semi-join*. A semi-join is a subquery on another object in an `IN` clause to restrict the records returned.
The issue lies in the square brackets, you should have used round ones:

```sql
SELECT AccountId, Id, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId IN (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Sic = '6752')
```

Semi-joins are usually used in parent-to-child relationship, meaning that the main object is the parent (i.e. Account) and the one in the subquery is the child (i.e. Contact).
The opposite relationship, a child-to-parent relationships, doesn't need a semi-join, since you can use dot notation both in `SELECT` field list and in `WHERE` clause as showed by eyescream

```sql
SELECT AccountId, Id, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Contact 
WHERE Account.Sic = '6752'
```

Of course if `Sic` is a custom field you should use its api name, i.e. `WHERE Account.Sic__c = '6752'`

Please note that in a child-to-parent relationships query, in order to use the dot notation, the lookup field suffix changes from `__c` to `__r`:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Account__r.AccountNumber 
FROM CustomObject__c 
WHERE Account__r.Industry = 'Banking'
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) to know semi-joins limits

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. 

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AccountId, Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Account.Sic = '6752'
```

Read up about relationships, for example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm

Comment: Thanks, Sir for your guidance 